Tracking Element in Viewport for Custom Animations in Wix Studio
I am developing a website using Wix Studio and need to track when an element enters the viewport during scrolling to trigger custom animations. Additionally, I want to track the element's offset height from the top while scrolling. Despite reviewing the available documentation and attempting to use the inbuilt features provided by Wix Velo, I was unable to find a solution that effectively tracks elements during scrolling.
Despite reviewing the available documentation and attempting to use the inbuilt features provided by Wix Velo, I was unable to find a solution that effectively tracks elements during scrolling.
